# Does register_shutdown_function work for nested functions

Tags: php, function, nested, shutdown

Suppose I have something like this,

```
<?php
   $test = new Test();
   register_shutdown_function(array($test, 'shutdownHandler'));
   $test->func1();

   Class Test {

     func1() {
        //code..
        func2();
     }

     func2() {
        //code..
        func3();
     }

     func3() {
        //code..
     }

     shutdownHandler() {
        //After func1 -> func2 -> func3 has finished, the handler should be called..
        //code..
     }
   }

?>
```

Will the register_shutdown_handler work in the above case?
Will the handler be called?

If not, how can I achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ??? I think nesting has nothing to do with shutdown function. http://ideone.com/Kdmj8q

Comment: Just created a test case, a bit complicated one though. And yes, the register_shutdown_function works fine. It calls the handler once all the code(after defining the register_shutdown_function) is executed. Thanks for you answer @CertaiN :)